# Sending SMS using free gateway

Tags: c#

I just wanted to develop one web application which allows users to send an SMS to any mobile free of charge . I searched on the net and found many codes and articles and through those articles i came to know that for that kind of application, i required either of the
following things:

1. Web service (Third party web services that are free but not working or not delivering the sms)
2. GSM Modem ( I don't have any idea about this)
3. SMS Gateway ( I don't have any idea about plz suggest me a idea

Comment: What magical articles are you talking about?

Comment: A GSM modem is a special modem which accepts a mobile phone SIM card and usually connects via USB to the computer on which the SMS gateway is hosted. Essentially, it functions as an automated mobile phone which you can send commands to it to send out SMSes.

Comment: This question appears to be more about "How can I send an SMS for free?" then anything that is actually programming related. There could be a programming related follow up once a free (yeah, right) SMS provider is located, but for the moment I believe this is off-topic.

Answer (score 3):

An SMS gateway is basically an API (usually a webservice) which you can call to send the SMS's. If you're not going to send very high volumes I think this is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like: [ZeepMobile](http://www.zeepmobile.com/)

They seem to have a pretty good guide as to how a developer would go about using their API, which can easily be applied to most SMS APIs out there.

Answer (score 1):

So who is going to pay for the SMS? If the user isn't, then either the receiver or yourself will have to - telco's don't carry SMS messages for free, and they charge each other termination fees when messages arrive on their network from another.